# need to obtain the public IP of the user but getting the IP of the server where the app is deployed

Tags: java, ip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding out your website visitor IP address in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483220/finding-out-your-website-visitor-ip-address-in-java)

I want to maintain logs for my website. For that I need to store the public IP of the visitor. How can I do that ? Till know I this was what I have been doing :

```
         URL ip = new URL("http://api.externalip.net/hostname/");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ip.openStream()));
        String publicIP = br.readLine();
```

but this returns me the IP of the server , I guess where the page is hosted. For example I always get the IP as : `76.xxxxxxxx` but when I check from [`whatismyip`](http://whatismyip.com) I have something like `106.xxxxxxx` .

How can I get this IP ? Which is the public IP of the user from which it visits the website.

Answer (score 1):

With every [Request](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) to your web application, client's IP is sent too. So all you need to do is to have [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) over `Requests`. Gain and store any information you like.