# extracting the IP sent in the request from client

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ip, httprequest

I was reading that *"With every Request to your web application, client's IP is sent too. So all you need to do is to have Filter over Requests and you can store the IP. "*

If this is so,how can I do this ? I mean what is the method that can tell me the IP sent in the request ?

Comment: where were you reading that and what have you tried so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to accurately determine the IP address of a client in java servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326138/is-it-possible-to-accurately-determine-the-ip-address-of-a-client-in-java-servle)

Comment: @Dominik in the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242915/need-to-obtain-the-public-ip-of-the-user-but-getting-the-ip-of-the-server-where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Filter class that implements [`javax.servlet.Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html), and fetch the IP from `ServletRequest` using `getRemoteAddr()`:

```
public final class ExtractIpFilter implements Filter {
    private FilterConfig filterConfig = null;

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
    }
    public void destroy() {
        this.filterConfig = null;
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
         throws IOException, ServletException {
      String ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
      // do something with the IP
   }
}
```

If your client is behind a proxy, try using `request.getHeader("x-forwarded-for")` instead, though this may or may not work depending on the configuration of the proxy.

Comment: I get this output : `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Try `request.getHeader("x-forwarded-for")`.

Comment: when i visit whatismyip.com it says no proxy detected

Comment: @grassPro: Are you accessing the server yourself? `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` is the loopback address in the IPv6 protocol. Try accessing from a different machine.

Comment: I can see the IP and thanks for _x-forwarded-for_ . It is a good thing